# Can the parent nodes of clusters formed using disjoint set forest be used as cluster representative?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining

The intention is to merge clusters which have similarity higher than the Jaccard similarity based on pairwise comparison of cluster representative. My logic here is that because the child nodes are all under the parent node for a cluster, it means that the parent node is somewhat like a representative of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The parent node is the aggregated cluster.

It's not a single point, so you can't just use it as representative.

But you can use the medoids, for example.